# Which directive I can run before ssl_certificate_by_lua_block to get user-agent information in openresty

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I am using OpenResty to generate SSL certificates dynamically.
I am trying to find out the user-agent of request before running `ssl_certificate_by_lua_block` and decide If I want to continue with the request or not.

I found out that `ssl_client_hello_by_lua_block` directive runs before `ssl_certificate_by_lua_block` but if I try to execute `ngx.req.get_headers()["user-agent"]` inside `ssl_client_hello_by_lua_block` I get the following error

```
2022/06/13 09:20:58 [error] 31918#31918: *18 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: ssl_client_hello_by_lua:6: API disabled in the current context
stack traceback:
coroutine 0:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /usr/local/openresty/lualib/resty/core/request.lua:140: in function 'get_headers'
    ssl_client_hello_by_lua:6: in main chunk, context: ssl_client_hello_by_lua*, client: 1.2.3.4, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

I tried `rewrite_by_lua_block` but it runs after `ssl_certificate_by_lua_block`

Are there any directive that can let me access `ngx.req.get_headers()["user-agent"]` and run before `ssl_certificate_by_lua_block` as well?

My Nginx conf for reference.

**nginx.conf**

```
# HTTPS server
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    rewrite_by_lua_block {
        local user_agent = ngx.req.get_headers()["user-agent"]
        ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "rewrite_by_lua_block user_agent -- > ", user_agent)
    }

    ssl_client_hello_by_lua_block {
        ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "I am from ssl_client_hello_by_lua_block")
        local ssl_clt = require "ngx.ssl.clienthello"
        local host, err = ssl_clt.get_client_hello_server_name()
        ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "hosts -- > ", host)
        -- local user_agent = ngx.req.get_headers()["user-agent"]
        -- ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "user_agent -- > ", user_agent)
    }

    ssl_certificate_by_lua_block {
      auto_ssl:ssl_certificate()
    }
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/resty-auto-ssl-fallback.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/resty-auto-ssl-fallback.key;
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend_proxy$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is facing the same issue.
[Here](https://groups.google.com/g/openresty-en/c/MS90_y8EgzA/m/wBHIQDszBwAJ?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer) is the email group of OpenResty that helped me.

I was not thinking correctly. The certificate negotiation happens before a client send user-agent data(that comes in after the SYNACK reaches the client). So you cant save issuing the certificate in the process. Hard luck.

Once the `handshake` and the `Client/Server Hello` happens then the server has the `user-agent`, you can do the blocking under `access_by_lua_block`.

Comment: The "second request" term is incorrect. It isn't a second request, it is an encrypted payload of the request, which is not available before the SSL handshake is done.